# How do I get Chrome to open local SVG files instead of downloading?

Tags: google-chrome, download, svg

Much like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531061/image-url-downloads-the-image-instead-of-displaying-it I have a Chrome browser that refuses to display *local* SVG files rather than dowloading them.

- I have updated Chrome to the latest version.
- I have reset settings and flags to default.
- Platform is PC.
- The Chrome browser is managed through GSuite.
- It does NOT help setting Chrome as default viewer for SVG files.
- It does NOT help enabling `Always open files of this type` (in fact, in combination with setting Chrome as default viewer it stars a download SVG loop).
- Opening SVGs from an online resource, for example https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg, DOES work.

  - Downloading that SVG and opening it with Chrome does NOT, however. It just re-downloads the file.

Any suggestions?